# How to affect multiple sheets from a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On Google Sheets, I want to hide rows with the value `'Del'` across my whole document, meaning multiple sheets. Additionally, I would like this to only happen when I update cell `E39` from Sheet `'Pricing breakdown'`.

My current code is working perfectly for sheet `'Pricing breakdown'`, but I would like it to also affect sheets `'Project Plan'` and `'Payment Plan'`, plus bonus points if you can help me only run this script when I change `E39` from sheet `'Pricing breakdown'`.

```
function onEdit(event){
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Pricing breakdown');
      s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('A:A')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'Del') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Pricing breakdown'){return;}
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E39') {
    var shA=['Pricing breakdown','Project Plan','Payment Plan'];
    for(var j=0;j<shA.length;j++) {
      var s=e.source.getSheetByName(shA[j]);
      s.showRows(1,s.getMaxRows());
      //e.source.toast(s.getName());
      s.getRange('A:A').getValues()
      .forEach( function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] == 'Del') 
          s.hideRows(i + 1);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.

Comment: Still :( TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.

Tried running from the editor and testing it live and stopped working on the first sheet as well.

Comment: I hope you realize this is not the kind of function that you can run from the script editor.